# Google Font doesn't load in Safari

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

Im working on this website:
[poschbuchhandlung.at/hu/index.html](http://poschbuchhandlung.at/hu/index.html)

I tried to implement a Google Font with @font-face:

```css
 @font-face {
font-family: 'Inconsolata';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url('../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: local('Inconsolata Regular'), local('Inconsolata-Regular'),
url('../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
url('../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
url('../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
url('../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.svg#Inconsolata') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

This does work in Firefox but not in Safari!And I can't figure out how, I already spend furious hours browsing the internet!
What is the problem? Do you have any guess?
Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have `inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.ttf` in your folder?

Comment: yes ist there like all the other fonts...Im really stuck at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font is inside /hu folder

Instead of:

```
../fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.ttf
```

Use:

```
 ../hu/fonts/inconsolata-v18-latin-regular.ttf
```

Comment: Is this a Safari specific thing? Or why did it work on Firefox thou?

Comment: Nope, check errors in your console. Maybe the route only exist for firefox